# Multiplication of 4 matrices in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Good evening,

I'm working on some matrix multiplication and I have run into a bit of a calculation issue. I have 4 matrices $A=(n \times1),B=(n \times p),C=(p\times 1),D=(n \times n)$, note that $D$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite. I am working on the following matrix multiplication,

$$
\begin{align}
(A-BC)^TD(A-BC) &=(A^T-C^TB^T)D(A-BC) \\
&=(A^TD-C^TB^TD)(A-BC) \\
 &=A^TDA-A^TDBC-C^TB^TDA+C^TB^TDBC
\end{align}
$$
And all I really want to know is if the calculation I did was done correctly. I carried out the multiplication of the dimensions by hand and all the matrix multiplications can be carried out. I have a feeling that the two middle terms $A^TDBC-C^TB^TDA$ could be combined into one but I am unsure of how to go about it.

Thank you.

Comment: If $B$ is $1 \times p$ and $C$ is $p \times n$, $BC$ is $1 \times n$, and it's impossible to do $A - BC$ if $A$ is $n \times 1$.  Are you sure you don't mean $A$ is $1 \times n$?

Comment: Hey Robert,
Thank you for noticing that. I had a minor typo in between B and C but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two middle terms *cannot* in general be combined when you multiply two binomials in a non-commutative ring, such as with matrices. For example,
$$
(X + Y)^2 = (X + Y) \, (X + Y) 
= X^2 + XY + YX + Y^2 
$$
does not simplify (unless $YX$ is some scalar multiple of $XY$ such as being symmetric or skew-symmetric).

However, in your calculation, if you track dimensions, the quantity is $1$-dimensional, and of course a $1 \times 1$ matrix (i.e. a scalar) *is always* symmetric. Using the fact that $D^\top = D$ for the first equality and this observation about dimensions for the second equality,
$$
C^\top B^\top D A = (A^\top D B C)^\top = A^\top D B C, 
$$
so you can combine the two terms and throw in a coefficient of $2$.

Comment: Awesome thank you. THis answers my question completely.